# Using llvm::Function::dump(), linker gives "undefined reference to `llvm::Value::dump() const'"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm trying to generate LLVM IR code, which I have done successfully as part of the [Kaleidoscope tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/) on this same machine, using these same compiler flags.

My code compiles without errors in clang++ 3.4. However, at link time I'm getting:

```
undefined reference to `llvm::Value::dump() const'
```

The error is being triggered by the line:

```
if (generator.code()) // returns llvm::Function*, or NULL
  generator.code()->dump();
```

If I remove the call to `dump()`, the linker is happy.

Clang++ flags I'm using are:

```
-O3 -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I./src `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native`
```

I'm confused, because the Kaleidoscope project compiles and runs fine and uses the same compiler flags and is built on the same computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking with libraries the libraries has to be placed *after* the source/object files.

So you need something like

```
clang++ -O3 -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I./src \
    `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags core jit native` \
    objectfile1.o objectfile2.o \
    `llvm-config --libs core jit native` \
    -o outputfile
```

It's because the linker looks for symbols in the order they are given on the command line.

Comment: Ah, that is definitely different! I was hand-writing the build script in the other project and has my source files first. In the new project, they are just in `CXXFLAGS` so my Makefile is putting the source files after them. I'll restructure things a bit :)

Comment: Problem solved by simply moving `$(CXXFLAGS)` to be after the source files, thank you! Will accept in a few mins once the SO time restriction has passed.

Comment: I personally prefer to split the linker command into a `$CXXFLAGS` (Or raterh `$LDFLAG` for the linker side) and a `$LIBS`.